# My codes can render but doesn't stay on localhost, what is wrong?

Tags: reactjs

i'm making a navabar. It shows up at first on localhost but can't stay any longer and then the console announced the mistake like my image below:
[image]

This is my Header.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";

function Header() {
    return ( <
        div class = "header" >
        <
        img src = "https://rdwgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Amazon-800x450-1.jpg" / >
        <
        div class = "header-search" >
        <
        input type = "text"
        className = "header-searchInput" / >

        <
        /div> <
        div className = "header-navbar" >
        <
        div className = "header-option" >
        <
        span class = "header-optionLineOne" > x < /span> <
        span class = "header-optionLineTwo" > o < /span> < /
        div > <
        div className = "header-option" >
        <
        span class = "header-optionLineOne" > x < /span> <
        span class = "header-optionLineTwo" > o < /span> < /
        div > <
        div className = "header-option" >
        <
        span class = "header-optionLineOne" > x < /span> <
        span class = "header-optionLineTwo" > o < /span> < /
        div > <
        /div> < /
        div >
    )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: why are you writing your html in such a weird way ?

Comment: Get rid of all these linebreaks and spaces between `<` and `div`, `<` and `/ ` and so on. There is no reason to put a space between each and every word/character.

Comment: one more thing. In react we dont use `class` we use `className`

Comment: Those are just my codes auto formatting, i didn't do that on purpose

Comment: yah i changed all of them to className but it's still not working..

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";

function Header() {
    return (
        <div class="header">
            <img src="https://rdwgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Amazon-800x450-1.jpg" />
            <div class="header-search">
                <input type="text" className="header-searchInput" />
            </div>{" "}
            <div className="header-navbar">
                <div className="header-option">
                    <span className="header-optionLineOne"> x </span>{" "}
                    <span className="header-optionLineTwo"> o </span>{" "}
                </div>{" "}
                <div className="header-option">
                    <span className="header-optionLineOne"> x </span>{" "}
                    <span className="header-optionLineTwo"> o </span>{" "}
                </div>{" "}
                <div className="header-option">
                    <span className="header-optionLineOne"> x </span>{" "}
                    <span className="header-optionLineTwo"> o </span>{" "}
                </div>{" "}
            </div>{" "}
        </div>
    );
}
```

i formatted your code and got rid of all the weird spaces. Also changed class to className where needed. Try this.

Comment: my codes are just automatically formatted when i hit save and that's when all the weird spaces show up, i don't know why